# firebaseui authentication with microsoft error: provider_id undefined

Tags: vue.js, firebaseui

I added firebase authentication to a Vue project and everything's working fine, except the Microsoft authentication.
Keep in mind that I already enabled the sign-in method using Microsoft and I tested with 2 credentials (one which are used in other project which is working fine and another newly created set).

This is my Auth.vue component

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Auth",
  mounted() {
    const uiConfig = {
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: authResult => {
          this.$store.dispatch("setUser", authResult.user);
          console.log(this.$route.params.redirectURL);
          if (this.$route.params.redirectURL) {
            this.$router.push("/" + this.$route.params.redirectURL);
          } else {
            this.$router.push("/");
          }

          return false;
        }
      },
      signInOptions: [
        this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        this.$firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        this.$firebase.auth.MicrosoftAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        this.$firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        this.$firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        this.$firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ]
    };

    this.$firebaseui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
  }
};
</script>
```

If the "this.$firebase.auth.MicrosoftAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID," is not commented, an error will occur, else, everything is working fine.
The error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER_ID' of undefined"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [firebaseui-web docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#customizing-firebaseui-for-authentication) I found out how to set it

```
signInOptions: [
            this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            this.$firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            this.$firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            this.$firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            "microsoft.com",
            "apple.com",
            "yahoo.com"
            //this.$firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            //this.$firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
          ]
```